# SQL group by precission for floats

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a slightly odd issue. I need to group a SQL result by a defined precision. The database system is PostgreSQL and we have a couple of hundred million values in total.

For example, consider I have a list of the following masses

1. 1.0005
2. 1.0010
3. 3.0000
4. 4.0016
5. 4.0014

these are all chemical masses in Dalton and I want to group them by +/-5 mDa in one materialized view and +/- 10mDa in another materialized view. So by 0.0005 and 0.0010.

Could anyone assist with this?

Comment: Hint: `SELECT TRUNC(4.0016 * 10000 / 5), TRUNC(4.0014 * 10000 / 5), TRUNC(4.0016 * 10000 / 10), TRUNC(4.0014 * 10000 / 10)`.

Comment: your question is not clear , give us some example of desired output

Comment: Are they actually floating point or decimal type?

Answer (score 0):

thank you at @Jeroen Mostert this seems to do the trick.

select avg(ion) as ion, sum(intensity) as intensity from result_annotations_msms racm  where "method" = 'a' and target_id  = 'b' group by TRUNC(ion * 1000 / 5)